# can you organize Document Set libraries into Folder Heirarchy?

Tags: 2010, folder, document-set

In my sharepoint designer workflow i create a document set when a project initiation form is submitted. the workflow creates the document set in a document set library. I'd like to organize a folder heirarchy at the ROOT level so that document sets are created in specific folders. I want to do this because in TFS i have the Documents show up in classic folders. without having a root heirarchy the flat list of folders grows too quickly and is unmanageable.  i've attempted to create folders within the document set library at the root but when navigating into them i don't have the option of creating a document library. HELP!

Comment: this article states we CAN place document sets in folders, HOW??  http://sharepointresourcecenter.com/sharepoint-document-sets-limitations-and-things-to-be-aware-of.html

Comment: i've seen someone doing it via WebDav - but soon after it started to behave eradically, particularly when you build solutions on top of it. Not recomanded practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added the Document Set content type to the allowable content types for my folder content type, and i was able to create the folder heirarchy manually, then programmaticly create the document set instances to the right folder node based on rules in my infopath form, through workflow. works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Document Sets are not meant to support hierarchical folder structure and any kind of tweaking (though possible via some tricks, such as WebDav folder copying, etc.) you are in for trouble. You should rely still maybe better on creating your own custom content types - based on Folder CT but with custom attributes (e.g Area, Iteration columns - if you are talking TFS).

Then you could enable Metadata based navigation and in addition to that benefit from Content Organizer which could, based on the custom content type attributes, re-organize physically your files/documents. You are in charge of the rules and it happens as soon as attributes are configured. Also, by configuring Default Metadata at each Folder level, you could ensure that child documents inherit metadata just by being placed in a respective folder.

Comment: metadata navigation is useless in a TFS Explorer view.  that's my problem with it.  i've added the document set content type to the Folder allowed content type, and i am able to create the document set inside the folder.  now i'm stuck on dynamical link preservation into my initiation form, to the document set.  deconstructing the query i see i now have to contend with a FOLDER GUID and i don't know how/if i can do that dynamically.

Comment: TFS Explorer view has nothing to do with SharePoint and it is not capable to understand this concept, as you well pointed out, but on the other hand, the same applies for Document-Sets. So folders still are you best friend, but applying metadata, at least in SharePoint you benefit from these automations and proper content tagging & clasification.

Comment: TFS explorer is indeed hooked up to my Sharepoint site and i can see all the contents of my sharepoint libraries under TFS Explorer.